# How to store multiple values from a function in Python in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I would store the values returned from a function in a Pandas DataFrame.

My URLs for scraping are stored in a Dataframe.

My function works like that:

```
def scrape(urls):
    price=[]
    title_box=[]
    try: 
        response = requests.get(urls)
        r = bs(response.text, "html.parser") 
        title_box = r.find('span', {'class': 'im-titleBlock__title'}).text.strip() 
        price = r.find_all('section', {'class': 'im-structure__mainContent'})
    except: 
        price='No'
        title_box='No'

    return title_box, price
```

I apply the function to my DataFrame of links using Lambda.

```
df=df['list_urls'].apply(lambda x: scrape(x))
```

It returns me a series,

I would like to have a Dataframe like this:

list_urls | title_box | price

Thank you so much.

Comment: give a few rows of what `df` looks like

Comment: ['Appartamento ', '€ 180.000', 'https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/90562771/']
['Bilocale', '€ 160.000', 'https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/91673852/']
['Quadrilocale', '€ 250.000', 'https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/91673548/']

Comment: what are the column names?

Comment: df.columns = ['list_titles', 'list_prices', 'list_urls']

Comment: your function doesn't get `price` in the `try:` block. whats `prezzo`?

Comment: My function is too long to post, it was just an example of the whole code. Sorry. 

The main point is how to write a dataset with a function that returns two values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, provided you'll have the `price` within the function:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd


data = [['Appartamento ', '€ 180.000', 'immobiliare.it/annunci/90562771/'],
         ['Bilocale', '€ 160.000', 'immobiliare.it/annunci/91673852/'],
         ['Quadrilocale', '€ 250.000', 'immobiliare.it/annunci/91673548/']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['list_titles', 'list_prices', 'list_urls'])

def scrape(urls):
    url = 'https://www.' + urls
    price=[]
    title_box=[]
    try: 
        response = requests.get(url)
        r = bs(response.text, "html.parser") 
        title_box = r.find('span', {'class': 'im-titleBlock__title'}).text.strip() 
        prezzo = r.find_all('section', {'class': 'im-structure__mainContent'})
        price = '??'
    except: 
        price='No'
        title_box='No'

    return title_box, price 


df['title_box'],df['price'] = df['list_urls'].apply(lambda x: scrape(x)).str
df = df[['list_urls', 'title_box', 'price']]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
                          list_urls                                        title_box price
0  immobiliare.it/annunci/90562771/  Appartamento buono stato, secondo piano, Padova    ??
1  immobiliare.it/annunci/91673852/       Bilocale ottimo stato, primo piano, Padova    ??
2  immobiliare.it/annunci/91673548/       Quadrilocale nuovo, su più livelli, Padova    ??
```